Why does OCaml implement List.map with a special case for a singleton?
OCaml implements map over lists like so:
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec map f = function
    [] -> []
  | [a1] ->
      let r1 = f a1 in
      [r1]
  | a1::a2::l ->
      let r1 = f a1 in
      let r2 = f a2 in
      r1::r2::map f l

To me this seems equivalent to this:
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec map f = function
    [] -> []
  | a1::l ->
      let r1 = f a1 in
      r1::map f l

Why is map implemented the way that it is, rather than the more concise way?

This question is a follow on from Tail recursive List.map

Seems like it has to do with "tail recursion modulo cons": https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/11362

Using git blame leads to a commit itself referencing the PR it originated in. The discussion there is interesting: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/11362 and highlights that manual unrolling simply makes the function faster.

It seems to me they just want to be able to do a1::a2::l -> (f a1) :: f(a 2) :: map f l instead of a :: l -> (f a) :: map f l; which might (or might not) be faster since you advance in the list two elements at once instead of just one.

Does this answer your question? Implementation of List.of_seq
